# ReactJS + Express Cache Busting issue

Tags: reactjs, express, caching, html-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to avoid cache busting by setting version numbers in the index.html file name (index.hash.html) generated with html-webpack-plugin. However, I'm unable to get the browser to grab the new file from the server  because the old index.html file is still cached for X amount of time.

I could clear cache to hit the server again, or change the cache-control header but this doesn't really work well for users that already have the file cached since it seems they won't see the changes to cache-control anyway. I'm looking for the correct solution and can't seem to find one for this issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on this, but we're using no hashing for `index.html`. This means the TTL for it is zero.

On the other hand, all other assets ( js, css , svg ... ) have hashes defined and are cached. Our Service worker on the client checks for newer versions and serve them accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm so I've removed hashing again and noticed max-age is set to zero, which should check for a new version I'd assume (but it isn't). However I am using a service worker that I should've researched more, must be what is keeping pages from refreshing..